# Is it possible to launch another app from within my sandboxed app?

Tags: swift, permissions, app-store, sandbox

I want to use IOKit for reading Fan speeds but unfortunately I am not allowed to publish the app on the MAS because of this.
So my app (let's call this A) can not read the data directly from IOKit, but would it be possible to encapsulate this feature into another app (this would be B)?
When starting the app, a popup would appear asking the user if he wants to use this feature and download the required helper app (B). When clicking yes, the app B is downloaded and started from within app A.

Is this

a) possible (sure, why not?) and more importantly
b) something that Apple would approve?

I already saw a thread here on this site about the entitlement

com.apple.security.temporary-exception.sbpl

I tried adding that entitlement and of course, my app works as intended. But Apple wouldn't approve this entitlement, would they? Even with a detailed description why I need that entitlement? Are there any developers that had Apple approve their app with this entitlement?

Regards,
inexcitus

Comment: this are two different questions. i answered first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they will approve if the download for B is not mandatory and marked as optional download. So App A still does something useful without B.

Comment: Thank you. App A still does something useful and B is NOT mandatory. If the user wants to download B, it is a sandboxed app and of course it is developer signed.